# What is this called?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, water, pump

I'm looking for a water container that functions like the one on the bottom, as water flows out of the container, the "cap" goes down, no air gets in. I don't know what it's called or what keywords to use. English is not my native language.

[image]

I need it so I can increase the water flow rate of the container by placing a weight on the cap.

I'm aware of alternatives, I'm just interested in this particular setup, just a tank, with a weight placed on top to increase flow rate. Any help?

P.S., ignore all the other parts in the image, it's just an image I came by in a physics forum and it include the part I want.

Comment: Note that as you've shown it here, it's a perpetual motion machine. That won't work. There are ways to use continuous low water pressure to intermittently get brief periods of higher water pressure, but you can't overcome thermodynamics.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

A piston pump compared to a plunger pump, from Wikipedia. The parts you specified from your picture are piston pumps.

> A piston pump is a type of positive displacement pump where the high-pressure seal reciprocates with the piston.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SBLY.png) Piston pumps can be used to move liquids or compress gases.

Comment: Thanks, it fits the description The component I posted above turns out to be called "piston cylinder" or "piston tube". I'm  looking for something bigger to execute what I mentioned earlier, any ideas?

P.S., I don't have enough points to upvote you.

Comment: Do you have anything yet or you plan to purchase parts to make one? It'd be good to know its purpose, too. @Cortez9

Comment: Nothing yet, planning to purchase any parts necessary to build one. 
The purpose as stated, to increase the output flow rate of a small water tank placed in a small area without using machines, electricity or manually creating pressure with air by continuously pressing a handle, like the manual garden water sprayers.
Getting a bigger tank increases output pressure/flow rate, but it consumes more space which I prefer to avoid.  @Mazura

Comment: It's intended for indoor use where electricity and water are not always available.  @Mazura

Comment: Sounds like your currently trying to use a gravity feed? Put the tank on the roof. You get a 1/2 pound of pressure for every foot you raise it up. That's why water tanks are 80 feet in the air, to get 40 psi. With no air compression the only factor to increase flow rate is the size of the inlets, and the water pressure feeding them, not tank size. Only if the tank is *taller* would you get more pressure. Consider a foot air pump to charge a holding tank with air, pressurizing the water. It would be better for a while. @Cortez9

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do (wasn't familiar with the term until now). Thanks for the tips, especially the foot air pump. @Mazura